# What is the difference between boost and translation in Galilean Transformation?

Tags: coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

This is probably a newbie question (but I guess is what I am right now) but I can't understand de difference between Galilean Boost and Galilean Translation.

I thought a boost was something like an S' frame of reference with constant velocity in relation to an S frame of reference. Mathematically:

$$  x' = x - vt; y' = y; z' = z; t' = t$$

so a boost would be an uniform motion between these to frame of reference and a translation would be an S'' frame of reference "fixed" but the origins dislocated in relation with S.

The thing is: I found in pdf files (and wikipedia) that these equations of a galilean transformation is actually a translation. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A boost refers to a coordinate transformation associated with a change in velocity and is mathematically equivalent to a translation of the coordinates by $vt$ where $v$ is the velocity and $t$ is time. This type of translation is not constant in time. On the other hand, a translation is a constant shift in coordinates.

Comment: So the exemple I made is a boost while something like x' = x - cst; .... t' = t - cst2 is a trasnlation?

Comment: Are $cst$ and $cst2$ constants?

Comment: Yes they are!!!

Comment: In that case yes, the case in you comment above is a translation.